# Terminal showing 'no such file or directory' for PATH variable on startup

Tags: bash, path-variables

When i start my Terminal i get this message:

```
bash: cd: PATH=/Users/ryan/Users/ryan/Documents/Pebble-Dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA3/bin:/Users/ryan/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin: No such file or directory
```

I realize there are multiple PebbleSDKs and the first one's path is definitely wrong.  Cannot find where this is getting pulled from.

Also, when i type `echo $PATH` into terminal i get:

```
/Users/ryan/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/ryan/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/ryan/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/ryan/Documents/Pebble-Dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA3/bin:/Users/ryan/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.0-BETA4/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-head@global/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-head/bin:/Users/ryan/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Which is also not right since it has even more **multiple** PebbleSDKs in it.

I have three questions:
1) Where is the inital PATH getting pulled from?
2) Where is the `echo $PATH` pulling from?
3 Why are they different?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

This is what i have in `/etc/bashrc`:

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize
# Tell the terminal about the working directory at each prompt.
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ] && [ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    update_terminal_cwd() {
        # Identify the directory using a "file:" scheme URL,
        # including the host name to disambiguate local vs.
        # remote connections. Percent-escape spaces.
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
    }
    PROMPT_COMMAND="update_terminal_cwd; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
fi
```

This is what i have in `/etc/profile`:

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
[ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

Where would the `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.profile` files you mentioned be located?

Comment: The real question is, where in your configuration files are you trying to pass the assignment to `PATH` as an argument to `cd`?

Comment: I have no idea...not my machine this is happening on. Where could i start to look for for that?

Comment: `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, and `.profile` would be good places to start. Less likely but possible would be system files like `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: @chepner, updated my question regarding your last comment.

Comment: They will be in your home directory, i.e. the directory you are in when you start a new Terminal.

Comment: That did it...there was a problem in the .bash-profile file and a bunch of stuff that didn't need to be in there.  Thanks!  If you make an answer i'll check it off for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `~/.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` for code that passes the assignment `PATH=...` as an argument to `cd`.

Comment: Could you expand upon this please? I'm quite new to Unix terminal and understand what you mean by "code that passes the assignment PATH=... as an argument to cd."

Comment: If a startup file contained a line like `cd PATH=...`, the shell would interpret that as a request to change the working directory to a one named `PATH=...`.